# SQLite database webview.db error on Android 4.0.4 using Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am using Phonegap on Android 4.0.3

I have created a database and then try to create some table and insert some data. Everything works fine on 4.2 but on 4.0.3 it just doesn't work.

I got the following error all the time

> sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error,
>   db=/data/data/com.vs.bettercommunity/databases/webview.db

Comment: Have you found an solution for this ?